# Map is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I keep getting this error that map is not defined. I changed my code around because of a regeneratorRuntime error and now I'm stuck with this one. Any help is appreciated!

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");

const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({heroes: []});
    useEffect(() => {
         const fetchData = async () => {
             const result = await axios(
                 'https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats',
             );
             setData(result.data);
         };
        fetchData();
            }, []);
    return(
        <ul>
            {data.heroes.map(item => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    <a href={item.name}>{item.localized_name}</a>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
};
export default App
```

Comment: check what the AJAX call returns: likely will not get a "heroes" array

Comment: What does the `require(‘regenerator-runtime/runtime’)` do for you?

Answer (score 1):

Define like this

```
setData({...data, heroes:result.data});
```

because you have pass heroes array variable to state so spread variable then set data

```
       useEffect(() => {
         const fetchData = async () => {
             const result = await axios(
                 'https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats',
             );
           setData({...data, heroes:result.data});
         };
        fetchData();
       }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from that API is just an array of objects. There is no key 'heroes'. So just do: `data.map(item =>...` and you should be good.

Comment: When I changed it it just spit back an error that data.map is not a function

Comment: nevermind it seems the bottom comment seemed to have fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

it'll working:

```
    import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react'

    import axios from 'axios'
    require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");

    const App = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState({heroes: []});
        useEffect(() => {
             // Using an IIFE
             ( async () => {
                 const result = await axios(
                     'https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats',
                 );
                 setData({...data, heroes: result.data || [] });
             })();
           }, []);
        return(
            <ul>
                {data.heroes.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <a href={item.name}>{item.localized_name}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    };
    export default App
```

Comment: What does the ’require('regenerator-runtime/runtime’` do here?

Comment: i just edit code @4156 _require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");_ is available

Answer (score 0):

`{data.heroes && data.heroes.map(item => (...`

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

The .map function is only available on array.

Check what type "data" is being set to, and make sure that it is an array.

Here, the heros data is not set to "data" so you need to add to "Data"

you can do by using setData({...data, heroes:result.data});

this will work for you!